# How do I define a custom snippet using VScode "Surround" extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, surround

I'm using a VScode extension called "Surround"

In the docs for this extension it shows how to define a custom snippet. What I want is really simple. I would like to add the ability to surround selected text with tags, ie <> </> while placing the cursors in the middle where I define what type of tag that is (html, img, button, etc)

The docs show this example:

```
    {
  "surround.custom": {
    // command name must be unique
    "yourCommandName": {
      // label must be unique
      "label": "Your Snippet Label",
      "description": "Your Snippet Description",
      "snippet": "burrito { $TM_SELECTED_TEXT }$0", // <-- snippet goes here.
      "languageIds": ["html", "javascript", "typescript", "markdown"]
    },
    // You can add more ...
  }
}
```

I can almost parse it, except I don't know what the placeholders are representing. I assume { $TM_SELECTED_TEXT } is the text I've selected but what is the trailing $0 used for? Also, how can I place 2 cursors in between the opening and closing tags?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Surround extension? just use `Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation`, `$0` is the location of the cursor at the end of the snippet, you should use a field like `$1` and use it multiple times, `<$1> </$1>`

Comment: I do use Emmet. This is a scenario where I want to select a block of html and wrap it in a div after the fact. I'm using the extension with the literal name "Surround" for vscode

Comment: `Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation` is exactly doing what you want, there are 2 extensions with the name `Surround`

Comment: https://github.com/yatki/vscode-surround

Comment: I checked out Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation. You're right.....that works. Thanks. I guess I like the Surround extension because I can just right click and pull up the surround extension rather than needing the additional step of opening up the command palette.

Comment: you can create a keybinding for this emmet command, you can even define the tag to wrap with so a simple key press and bob is your uncle